# What does 'the New Torah' in these medrashim mean?

Tags: midrash, messiah, kabbalat-hatorah, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

The Yalkut Shimoni on Yishaya, remez 429, mentions how Hashem will sit and be doresh a new Torah that he will give by the hand of Moshiach.

This medrash is apparently taken from the Osios diRabi Akiva ois Zayin, where we find this same term.

What does this mean? What it's this referring to? I understand this may be opening a Pandora's box but all I can say is 'oy li im omrah,oy li im lo omrah'.

Comment: Very interesting question. You may find the following link helpful:  http://www.chabad.org/library/moshiach/article_cdo/aid/1122210/jewish/Torah-Study-During-the-Messianic-Era.htm

Comment: See [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16067&st=&pgnum=116&hilite=) for a lengthy discussion on this concept.

Answer (score 6):

The Shai LaMorah, on Tannah D'vei Eliyahu Zuta 20:6, explains that Hashem will reveal yet-unknown reasons for the Mitzvos and the Torah. Our newfound understanding of the reasons will make it seem ***as if*** there's a new Torah.

He cites the Iyun Tefillah on the *yotzer* of Parshas Hachodesh.

Comment: Do you have a link? I can't seem to get my hands on it.

Answer (score -1):

*Let me present a different explanation.*

Torah has many concentric levels. Its outer level is Pshat, which represents the Halachah - the Law - the application of the Torah in this world. As we know, this world is not a goal on its own, but **a tool for achieving a higher spiritual state** (*by working out our primordial sins etc.*).

Once this level is reached (*and the sins are mended*), the evil inclination is cancelled, there will be no choice and hence no commandment, therefore there's no need for that layer of Halachah. The holidays will disappear, there will be no money, no lust, no transgressions. Obviously, **the Pshat will loose its meaning** - "don't steal?" -what do you mean by that? just like plants can't steal, we won't be able to steal.

Therefore, this new and higher "reading of Torah" could be called a "new Torah" for as, as we are used to the current level of reading it.

---

Possible ramifications (base on the above):

- The meaning of existing words will be altered to represent more spiritual concepts (as it is now on Drush and Remez levels).
- The written Torah as we know it, will be either literally rearranged and read differently.
- The Torah will return to its original Hebrew font.
- The letters will "dismantle" to represents the actual 600,00 letters.
- The Torah will loose punctuation and spaces (see #2), and read in more that 1 direction (dimension), as it is read now.

Comment: does the acceptance of a "new torah" presuppose the use of the term "old torah" or "old covenant" without any suggestion of avodat zarah?