# The torah is nothing now compared to that of moshiach? What does this midrash mean?

Tags: history, midrash, messiah

In koheles Rabba piska 11 ois 8
It says that "The Torah we have now is hevel-nothing compared to the Torah of moshiach".

Why is this Torah considered nothing? What is the Torah of moshiach mean?

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48330/what-does-the-new-torah-in-these-medrashim-mean and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48330/what-does-the-new-torah-in-these-medrashim-mean

Answer (score 3):

The prophet [Ieshaiahu perek 51 pasuk 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1051.htm) says: "Attend unto Me, O My people, and give ear unto Me, O My nation: **כי תורה מאתי תצא**". Chachomim explained this as referring to the time of geulah. In the words of midrash vaycra rabba 13:3: תורה חדשה מאתי תצא, חידוש תורה מאתי תצא

Or as stated by [Yalkut Shimoni 429](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?mefaresh=shimoni&book=12&perek=26):

> עתיד הקב"ה להיות יושב... ודורש תורה חדשה שעתיד ליתן על-ידי משיח

This mean that when moshiach comes, the knowledge of Torah he will reveal, transcends whatever will have been revealed until then. From this p.o.v., the quantification of moshiach's Torah will be an extraordinary revelation to be considered a "new torah" (Cf. [Midrash Talpiot 58a)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33215&st=&pgnum=116&hilite=).

Comment: It should be noted that Midrah Talpiot is a Sabbatean work.

Comment: @RenatoGrun that's nice but why is the Torah we have now considered hevel-nothing compared to Torah of moshiach is it really nothing

Comment: @menachem, this is answered in the last comment.  The insigths given by moshiach about torah and mitzvot  will  be as if all we know about this was nothing. It is a way of saying that the revelation of the secrets of Torah brought by him will be much better to what we have today.

Comment: Greater but not that this what we have now us nothing and worthless and valueless

Comment: @mevaqesh source?

Comment: @user6591 Wikipedia provides [this lik](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/YovelMarks/YovelMarks13.pdf) regarding the Sabbatean status of the author and the frequent Sabbatean references in his writings.

Comment: @mevaqesh from the man himself, Gershom Scholem. Ty.

Comment: @user6591 If I recall, rabbinic types have also denounced the work. It would be surprising of no one realized a work was sabbatean until the 20th century. Such, rabbis as Rabbi Yaakov Emden were excellent at detecting Sabbateans.

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't think anyone realizes. It's stocked in most major (I.e. ones with large libraries) batei medrashos and yeshivos. I have read it myself for entertainment purposes. I have never seen anything as condemning as what Prof Scholem was quoting. I haven't finished that article, but it seems his proofs to the author's sabatean leanings are all from a different work of his which he spent time proving was from the same author. He has a very long strange entry in M.T. about Moshiach, but never mentions the whole Moshiach utilizing kelipos(?!) like Scholem quotes him in that other work.